# Transfer function of a second order capacitive accelerometer

Tags: transfer-function, accelerometer, capacitive

In order to find the transfer function of the accelerometer MMA7361L based on the information given in the data sheet [1](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MMA7361L.pdf)  I first made a hypothesis that it a second order sensor since it has a resonance frequency

[image]

the frequency response would look like this
[image]

but when I came to express the proper frequency and the damping factor I expressed in terms of \$F_c\$ the cut off frequency and the resonance frequency \$F_r\$ but when I came to see in the data sheet the cut of frequency is 400Hz  and the resonant frequency is 6KHz which is making me confused because the cut off frequency should be after the resonance frequency, did I start from a wrong idea ? is there an other information that could help me get to the the proper frequency and the damping factor of my accelerometer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your approximation of the sensing element might work (although there is not enough data in the datasheet to back it up), but your are missing the filtering that is being done (the cutoff frequency you mention is for the filter, not for the sensing element). The *capacitive filter* filters the output of the sensing element and removes those high frequency components, but since the resonant frequency might have a really high peak (the datasheet doesn't mention the peak value) it might still show up fairly well in the output of the whole accelerometer.

Here is a quick sketch of what I mean by that,

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer I understood it well, so since it is the cut off frequency of the  filter there is no information about the cutoff frequency of the sensing element in the data sheet, is there any other information about the frequency response that I can use because I have two inknowns  the proper frequency and the damping factor and I got only one information which is the resonnant frequency that corresponds to the peak.

Comment: I would juts approximate the whole thing by a 1st order system (the capacitive low-pass filter). Do notice that a 6kHz mechanical frequency is very high, a lot of things would shake apart with way smaller frequencies, so in most applications you should not have much problem with that resonance showing up.

Comment: thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

The resonance value of 6 kHz in the data sheet is the mechanical resonance of the sensing element in the device. The cut-off frequency in the data sheet is that of the filter that processes the signal and has no relationship with the mechanical resonance: -

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer.